# Radio program with public transport focus by country

Tags: public-transport, europe, event-based-effects, communication

My local radio station - I am based in Berlin, Germany - does a really poor job when it comes to public transport (subway, bus, etc.) announcements like delays or construction works. Their main focus lies on the individual use of the car (radar traps, traffic jams, you name it). They do a frequent follow up on those every 30 minutes.

I was wondering, does anyone know a radio station which broadcasts a news program with a main focus on such things like public transport. I thought about to point my local station to such an example. I am really open to any suggestions and not limited to Germany or Europe.

Is there anything like this or is the lack of it a global phenomenon?

Comment: You'll need to be specify where you are based for this question to make any sense. Voting to close as "too broad" in the meantime.

Comment: @mts I added some geo information...although I don't think that this is really crucial it could be of some interest, agreed.

Comment: Much better, close-voted retracted, question should be open and +1

Comment: i guess this would make an awesome google car / apple carplay app.  "good morning eric, today's subways L1 to L3 will have a 20min delay according to our data..  do you want more public transport information, or start listening to your favourite stations?"

Comment: @CptEric haha or some bicycle related clothing recommendations...well, at least then the driver of the web5.0-car - which would be you, Eric - could understand my frustration induced by the terrible lack of relevant traffic information broadcasted by my favourite radio station

Comment: To be fair, i told google allo ( awesome app, try it out)  assistant to text me all those things every morning.

Comment: @CptEric oh, cool, I didn't know that this was possible with allo. Currently I rely on google now, which works so-so

Comment: you can tell him things like " give me the traffic information each morning"

Comment: @user190080  there you go http://i.imgur.com/fnOaHql.png

Comment: When nearly everyone got a smartphone, why to use the radio when the web can be specific to your circumstance of travel?

Comment: @SelaYair well, then you could also argue why anyone would listen radio in this first place. I for myself like to hear radio also on the way via my smartphone and would also like to get informed through this channel.

Comment: @CptEric why don't you make that an answer?!

Comment: (+1) Opinions aside, SelaYair is onto something. TV and radio channels still have stock market and the like but smartphones are sucking the air out of this kind of things. Teletext and weather bulletins over the phone already disappeared and I would speculate that it will be difficult to make a good case that a radio should invest any effort into something like that. Besides, in public transportation, unlike a private car, your hands are free.

Comment: @Relaxed true, soon it will be an anachronism to say I am watching TV or I am listening to the radio. Strictly speaking, you don't really need traffic reports on the radio, neither for car (any navigation app,bluetooth,voice commands) nor for public transport - you can get more reliable, since more current and sometimes directly from the source, information through the web/app. The question is, if you decide to broadcast such news, why not also for the public transport sector? At least my radio station doesn't, maybe in a more public transport friendly city they do and thats's what I am after

Answer (score 1):

It is not radio but this is the best sample, and most reliable repeated, I know.
When you watch BBC 1 breakfast, on the London version of the TV channel, you will see updates on how the underground runs.
They show the same screen as you find on entering the underground stations.
If there are huge delays on bus lines and the trains, they will also mention that. They do also mention main road blockages, but not as annoying as the every 30 minutes updates on the radio.

I have heard some train delays mentioned on the Dutch radio, likely Radio 2, but it can also have been 3 FM, and in special circumstances all Dutch radio stations will mention it. That is when there is a whole region of the country affected, or when the airport can not be reached by train.
Most of the time the trains are not mentioned unless the delays are big, not even on the best channel for it.

Even with this service, the car traffic information will take 10 times as much time. (And most of those delays are regular ones, which are there almost every day, so do not need every 30 minutes repeats.)

Comment: that's interesting that they do broadcast information on the TV but not so much on the radio. Here at my local radio station they broadcast every 30 minutes pretty much the same and often even redundant information, but really only for car traffic.

Comment: I do not listen to any London radio station, so I do not know whether those do include bus or underground information. I share your feeling about traffic information on the radio, I would chose a station without it. (But when at work, others select the station we all listen to.)

Answer (score 1):

I know of no such radio station and I suspect that at least in Germany they will be scarce and scattered if they exist at all.

From a historical point of view, radios were stationary in your home except for the one that you had in your car. There is an incentive for both sides — the police offering the (road) traffic data and the station broadcasting it — to include information on the road delays. The radio station can bind listeners to it if they give the impression of providing fast and complete coverage. On the other hand, the police gets a channel for public announcements they can use for e.g. wrong-side driver warnings.

No such benefit generally existed for railways or local public transport. Most importantly, most people would not have a radio with them on a bus or train.<sup>[1]</sup> And the public transport or railway companies typically don’t need to warn many people at once — if they do, they have speaker systems in place. Thus, no both-sided interest existed.

Nowadays, many transport associations and railway companies have introduced app services that tell you if things happen that could affect your journey. These are typically updated more or less in real time while a radio station would have to set aside a slot in their programm, which is typically only once every half-hour. So any radio-based solution is doomed to be slower and thus less helpful.

Of course, I could be prove wrong. If I listen to radio programs, it is the traditional radio wave-based stations. The internet may well have introduced a lot more that I am not aware of.

---

**Note:**

[1]: Of course, portable radios exist and some ICE generations also had radio programs that you could listen to with headphones at your seat. But these were more the exception than the rule: a few years ago people 
wearing headphones in the street were rare.

Comment: There is definitely a tradition in favoring cars over public transport when it comes to service announcements, which you have nicely explained (+1). Nevertheless I think a radio station could and should do a better job than announce pretty much no public transport news at all (maybe this is still rooted in the very car-centered idea of mobility).I could think of announcements à la heavy delays (especially during the winter),long temporally blockings. The radio I am listening to does not even offering any information on their website.

Comment: @user190080 Well, the radio stations I listen to do say *a little* in cases of extreme disruptions, i.e. the line being closed. But it is still a very rare case unfortunately.